# Call a function and method with the same name in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Forgive me for my english.
I am a php programmer and now i want to learn Ruby.
In php if you want to call function "foo" within a class, you simply call foo(), and if you want to call method "foo" you call this->foo().
The question is, is it possible to call function and method with the same name in Ruby?

For example:

```
def foo
  puts "In foo function"
end

class A
  def call_foo
    foo
    #How can i call foo function, not a method?
  end

  def foo
    puts "In foo method"
  end
end

a = A.new

a.call_foo #Prints "In foo method"
```

Comment: This is not how it's done in ruby. I suggest to forget all the bad habits PHP taught you or you will not have an easy time.

Comment: In short: there are usually no free-floating "functions" in a ruby app. They're all methods and belong to some object (ruby is heavily object-oriented). So your task is to find the appropriate object and call the method on it.

Comment: To elaborate on what @SergioTulentsev said, methods are always sent as messages to receivers (along with any arguments they may have). If there is no explicit receiver, `self` is implied. Here `call_foo` has an explicit receiver, an instance of `A` (`a`), but `foo`, invoked by `call_foo` does not. `foo` is therefore sent to `self`, which is also `a`. You can confirm that by inserting `puts "self=#{self}"` in `call_foo`, as the first line. Ruby is all about the value of `self` at any given time.  You'll learn a lot from adding `puts "self=#{self}"` here and there in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a function in Ruby, only methods.

If you define a method at the top-level it is an instance method of `Object`.

If you define a class without a superclass, it's superclass is `Object`.

So, your `A#foo` simply overrides `Object#foo`. And if it overrides `Object#foo`, it should respect its contract. You should never need to call `Object#foo` on an `A`, if `A#foo` implements `Object#foo`'s contract correctly (and it should, otherwise it would be a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle). If you want to reuse `Object#foo`'s implementation within `A#foo`, you can defer to the superclass implementation using `super`.

Note: what you want *is* possible using reflection, but the correct solution would be to fix your design:

```
def foo
  puts "In foo function"
end

class A
  def call_foo
    self.class.superclass.public_instance_method(:foo).bind(self).()
  end

  def foo
    puts "In foo method"
  end
end

a = A.new

a.call_foo #Prints "In foo function"
```

Answer (score 0):

The foo method outside of your class definition is bound to Object, which is an instance of Class. So to call your method you can do:

```
> Object.foo­
  => "In foo function"
```

But as it was pointed out before, you should rather declare this method in an appropiate class.

You can also declare this method as class method with:

```
class A
  def self.foo
    puts "In foo class method"
  end
end
```

Now you can call it without creating an A instance:

```
> A.foo
  =>  puts "In foo class method"
```